# Correct way for “Horizontal Paging” in iOS using Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mobile-development

I'm basically an Android developer, now learning iOS development using Swift. My Question is , What is the correct way to achieve horizontal paging in iOS , which can be used to implement "Card Swiping" , in which the card has text view which changes its text . What I mean is , the card and the text view should move together when we swipe horizontally and the next card should have the next text view. And I'll have an array of quotes and the number of pages should depend on the length of this array. So wanted to know what to use exactly , a "ScrollView" or a "CollectionView" or a "TableView"? And How to use it ?

Comment: Use them all and figure out which one suits you best for your needs.

Comment: Have you looked at `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: you can go for `UICollectionView` or flat `iCarousal`.

Comment: take a look https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/